# How to enable the checkbox so that the project on xamarin can be compiled under Windows?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Already searched the entire Internet and found nothing, please reply, otherwise you need to make an application for windows but I don’t know how.
[image]

Comment: did you select the UWP workloads when you installed VS?

Comment: Visual studio installer --> Modify --> Select Windows:.Net Desktop development.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not coding related but installation related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **Visual Studio Installer** -> Click **Modify** -> Check whether choose follow option (**Universal Windows Platform development**)

[image]